# Transitioning from AWS WorkMail to different mail server, but keeping AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

We are currently using AWS WorkMail for the email addresses of our team members, and we are using AWS SES to send automated emails from an EC2 instance.

Due to different reasons we want to move the email addresses of our team members to a different email service (not hosted on AWS). However, we want to continue to send emails from noreply@... using AWS SES.

What would be the best approach for this? I was thinking of the following:

- Setting the MX DNS-Entry to our new email server
- Setting the TXT DNS-Entry from `v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all` to `v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:ournewserver.com ~all`
- Sending emails using SMTP on the new server

Would that be a good approach? Is there anything else I have to do or anything else I have to keep in mind when doing those changes?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective this looks fine, I would recommend that you do it in a staged approach:

- Lower TTL records on all records
- Add the SPF record first as it should be non-breaking
- Update MX records/SMTP.

Lowering the TTLs will make for a quicker rollback. Try to seperate all steps with a gap longer than the TTL so that you can be more determined over how to rollback the particular step.